# What was the machine used for in Amnesia: A Machine for Pigs?

Tags: amnesia-a-machine-for-pigs

I'm sure I'm not the only one wondering about this.
I've read pretty much all the papers I could find wandering around, listened to all the dialog in the game, and I still didn't figure out **exactly** what that machine is.

So can someone help and explain:

- What exactly is this machine?
- Why was it built?
- What is it used for?

Comment: It was used for pigs, obviously. :P

Answer (score 1):

From a wiki entry -

"After he returned from his Mexican expedition, Mandus was consumed with obsession over a vision of the future from "the egg," hinted to be an Orb, in which both of his children killed at the Battle of the Somme. Driven mad by the vision, Mandus decided that he could not allow it to come to pass, and he built the Machine to create a godlike being via mass ritual human sacrifice to save humanity from its own carnage. He then killed Edwin and Enoch himself to spare their fate at the Somme."